# "Polymorphic" non-member functions/operators, do I need extra overloadings?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I want to override parent class overloaded operators but I'd like to avoid <s>boilerplate code</s> rewriting all non-member operators for inherited class. Is it possible at all?

In the following example, I overloaded `virtual Foo & Foo::operator+=(Foo const &)` and based a free function `Foo & operator+(Foo, Foo const &)` out of it. In Bar, I overrode `Bar & Bar::operator+=(Foo const &) override`. What I want is the free function to call the overriden function when I state `Bar + Foo` and I expect `Foo` as a result. I know that overloading again `Bar operator+(Bar, Foo const &)` solves for that particular situation but I'd like to avoid explicitly do that if possible (think about all the other operators). And then there's also `Foo + Bar` that I want to return `Bar`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(unsigned int bottles=11) : bottles(bottles) {} // This is odd on purpose

  virtual void display(std::ostream & out) const {
    out << bottles << " bottles";
  }

  virtual Foo & operator+=(Foo const &);

protected:
  unsigned int bottles;
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Foo const & f) {
  f.display(out);
  return out;
}

Foo & Foo::operator+=(Foo const &f) {
  bottles += f.bottles;
  return *this;
}

Foo const operator+(Foo f, Foo const & g) {
  return f += g;
}

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
  Bar(unsigned int bottles=0) : Foo(bottles) { enforce(); }
  Bar(Foo const & f) : Foo(f) { enforce(); }

  void display(std::ostream & out) const override {
    out << bottles << " manageable bottles";
  }

  Bar & operator+=(Foo const &) override;

private:
  void enforce() { bottles /= 2; bottles *=2; }
};

Bar & Bar::operator+=(Foo const &f) {
  Foo::operator+=(f);
  enforce();
  return *this;
}



int main () {
  std::cout << "----- Foo + Foo -----" << std::endl;
  Foo bar;
  Foo becue(2);
  std::cout << bar << " + " << becue << " -> (+) "
    << bar + becue << std::endl;

  std::cout << "----- Bar + Bar -----" << std::endl;
  Bar crazy(bar);
  Bar horse(5);
  std::cout << crazy << " + " << horse << " -> (+) "
    <<  crazy + horse << std::endl;

  std::cout << "----- Bar + Foo -----" << std::endl;
  std::cout << crazy << " + " << bar << " -> (+) "
    <<  crazy + bar << std::endl;

  std::cout << "----- Foo + Bar -----" << std::endl;
  std::cout << bar << " + " << horse << " -> (+) "
    <<  bar + horse << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I expect manageable bottles as a result each time manageable bottles are involved.

Comment: I recommend adding another sub-type of `Foo`. Call it `Baz`. And then, work out the policy of what should happen for all combinations of the LHS and the RHS of the `+=` operator. I have a feeling that will bring some clarity to your thinking.

Comment: One of the problem is that you are mixing operator + and operator +=. As a result (I presume) you used copies as parameters of your + operator to avoid them to be modified when you would really need const references to make the polymorphism work. But you can't as += would only take non const ref, as it modifies the object.

Comment: `template <class T> T operator+(T t, const Foo& f ){ return t += f;}` ? But then take care to not have any nontemplate operators defined for this hierarchy.

Comment: @ChrisR. In fact, it's pretty common for `operator+` to delegate to `operator+=` to have a consistent behavior between the two

Comment: @greendiod ok but not when you want polymorphism to work AND keep your l value unchanged

Comment: @RSahu Please can you elaborate? How does `Baz` interact with the parent and the sister class?

Comment: @greendiod, what should happen when the argument to `Bar::operator+=(Foo const &)` is a `Baz` object? Will there be a `Baz::operator+=(Foo const &)` also? What should happen when the argument to `Baz::operator+=(Foo const &)` is a `Bar` object?

Comment: @ChrisR. So you suggest to implement them separately ? As I confirmed in my comment to Jack's answer, the const reference wouldn't also work.

Comment: @RSahu In fact, I'd like all operations involving the derived class `Bar` to be a `Bar` object. Why do you want to add an extra sister class?

Comment: @Slava Can you elaborate?

Comment: @greendiod, that's precisely what I wanted you to think about. What I understand from what you told is that calling `Bar::operator+=()` with a `Baz` as the RHS should trigger a run time error. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @greendiod I thought that it would be bette to split them yes, but then you'll have to have only const method called from the + operator i.e you cannot call enforce the way it is for now.

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. For the example main function you give this template should work. And you do not even need to make your operator+ virtual. There is no run-time polymorphism in your example at all. Maybe you wound want to correct it to have Foo& foocr = crazy, and do something with that, but that will be a different story. Then you would probably need to forward T&& and do enable_if magic to differentiate from concrete types, and probably use "virtual constructor" as you figured out yourself.

Comment: I didn't see @Slava solution, it works on most cases excepts when you have your Bar on the right side of the +, but it's the best solution so far.

Comment: @Slava Ok, so you propose compile-time polymorphism and let the compiler write the non-member operator I don't want to.

Comment: @RSahu But I don't see your point of introducing a sister class in the first place. Maybe a hypothetical `Baz` interacting with parent `Foo` would return a `Baz` and a `Bar + Baz` would be meaningless (say `Baz` enforces botlles to be odd while `Bar` enforces them to be even, now another hypothetical `Buzz` might work with `Baz` and always return a `Buzz` which would require bottles to be a multiple of 3) ...

Comment: @greendiod, `Bar` cannot possible know about all the sub-types of `Foo`. It can only know about `Foo` and `Bar`. That means if the argument to `Bar::operator+=` is anything other than a `Bar`, it has to trigger an error. To notice that as an error it has to perform `dynamic_cast` on the argument to make sure that it is indeed a `Bar`.

Comment: @RSahu ok, I agree that `Bar` can't possibly know about all possible sub-types of `Foo`. So what you suggest in fact is to prevent any polymorphism at all to take place. But it still can be interesting to be able to do it if my domain problem is such that no sister class can ever arise (say e.g. that `Foo` is a general fraction and `Bar` is a fraction in reduced form where `enforce` is `reduce`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem derives from object slicing that occurs when invoking

```
Foo const operator+(Foo f, Foo const & g) {
  return f += g;
}
```

Here, `f` is passed by value, which means that any additional information of subtypes of `Foo` are discarded. So the compiler just sees a `Foo` and is not able to call the polymorphic operator.

To prevent slicing you are forced to pass a pointer or a reference, but this would imply that you need an `l-value` as first operand and you can't use `const` because you are calling `operator+=` on it.

So you could have

```
Foo const operator+(Foo& f, Foo const & g) {
  return f += g;
}
```

and it would work for your specific situation like:

```
Foo bar;
Bar crazy(bar);
std::cout <<  crazy + bar << std::endl;
```

Because `crazy` is an `l-value` but you won't be able to do `Bar(5) + horse` nor `Foo(5) + horse`.

Comment: I also thought about object slicing but I left `f` as is because I already tried `Foo const & f` and of course you're right, it won't even compile. Unless I use a temporary like in `return Foo(f) += g;`. With this approach, now I'm back at square one again (slicing at work). Unfortunately if  I simply pass `f` by reference as you suggest, I get really bizarre results!

Comment: Or maybe I could use a virtual constructor?